# error in upserting data in cosmos db.. results in modifying data in some other data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

In our project we are using asp.net and for database we have cosmos db and i was upserting the data into the database using an upsert API and i came to modifying data with the wrong data but i passed the right data .. can anyone resolve this ..

```
 case UpsertDataEnumtype.SUBCATEGORY:
 var jsonSubcategoryAsString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(upsertData);
 var SubcategoryList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<BbData<object>>>(jsonSubcategoryAsString);
```

thats how i am upserting for particular data using a enum value

so previously i was upserting all at a time but after modification we are doing for 1 at a time using switch case and the getting one is working fine but this one is having some issues

Comment: May be you share also the code you use to call Upset. Why did you not use the nugets wrapping the cosmos api?